# Error en peticion Retrofit + RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rxjava

Estoy iniciando con RxJava e intento fusionarlo a peticiones realizadas con retrofit (las cuales funcionan correctamente), pero me he topado con un error, el cual espero me puedan ayudar.
Les comparto fragmentos de mi código:
Mis dependencias:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
```

Esta es la interface:

```
public interface Calls {
    String KEY = "AIzaSyA7m5YQp_OQXvZ7DzylErwubKq7BhIVUcs";
    String BASE_URL="https://maps.googleapis.com/";

    @GET("maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?radius=2000&type=bank&key="+KEY)
    //Call<Basic<ArrayList<Place>>> getSities(@Query("location") String location);       //Utilizada con Retrofit
    Observable<Basic<ArrayList<Place>>> getSities(@Query("location") String location);//Utilizada con RXJava
}
```

Clase RetrofitClient

```
public class RetrofitClient {
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

y con esto pretendo obtener los datos:

```
RetrofitClient.getClient(Calls.BASE_URL).create(Calls.class)
            .getSities(LATITUDE+","+LONGITUDE)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(places -> {                   
                rvPlacesList.setHasFixedSize(true);
                PlaceAdapterRV adapterRV = new PlaceAdapterRV(places.getResults());
                rvPlacesList.setAdapter(adapterRV);
                rvPlacesList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
            });
```

Y este es el error que me arroja:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Cualquier sugerencia es bien recibida.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final el error término siendo algo tan simple... estaba incluyendo dependencias del adaptador rxjava1 de retrofit en vez de la de rxjava2. Bastó con modificar la dependencia y de paso actualizar la versión de 2.1.0 a 2.3.0.
Antes:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
```

Despues:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
```

Falta optimizar el manejo de la respuesta, pero el código ya funciona.